# ImageMagick fails to remove alpha in pdf to png conversion but only on some pages

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert a pdf to png files per page and removing the 4th alpha channel. ImageMagick is behaving weirdly in that it is removing alpha correctly for all but one page. Is there an error in my command?

Here is the pdf: http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3723-anomaly-detection-with-score-functions-based-on-nearest-neighbor-graphs.pdf

Command I'm executing:

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 -alpha remove nips09_4.pdf nips09_4.png
```

Result:

```
$ identify -verbose nips09_4-2.png
Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 2480x3508+0+0
  Resolution: 118.11x118.11
  Print size: 20.9974x29.7011
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Type: TrueColorAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 16-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 16-bit
    green: 16-bit
    blue: 16-bit
    alpha: 1-bit


$ identify -verbose nips09_4-1.png 
Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 2480x3508+0+0
  Resolution: 118.11x118.11
  Print size: 20.9974x29.7011
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Type: Palette
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 16-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 16-bit
    green: 16-bit
    blue: 16-bit
```

To reproduce:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3723-anomaly-detection-with-score-functions-based-on-nearest-neighbor-graphs.pdf
mv 3723-anomaly-detection-with-score-functions-based-on-nearest-neighbor-graphs.pdf nips09_4.pdf
convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 -alpha remove nips09_4.pdf nips09_4.png
```

Comment: Try using `-alpha off` instead, after loading the `PDF`, and see if that helps.

Comment: That's fixed it. Would you like to expand and explain as an answer below so I can give you some internet points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using -alpha off instead, after loading the PDF, and see if that helps. Like this:

```
convert -density 300 some.pdf -alpha off nips%03d.png
```

I believe `-alpha remove` will remove the *effect* of the alpha channel but actually leave it still present, but opaque, in the image and that gets transferred onwards to your `PNG` images.

In contrast, `alpha off` actually removes the channel altogether and so it doesn't show up in the `PNG` images.

Comment: unfortunately this has broken pages with images (it makes them black apart from the images). I'll add to my question for code to reproduce quickly.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I put it in the wrong place! Cheers for quick solution.